# Cannot Install Cordova Plugin FCM Ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging, cordova-plugins, ionic4

I am trying to install the cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependency-updated on my project(Ionic4). There's no problem on Android but in IOS, I encountered this kind of error.

[image: Installation Error on IOS]

Here's my Ionic Info

[image: Ionic Info]

Comment: Hi, are you able to solve this issue? I am facing exactly the same issue on IOS, i tried google and everything, created new Ionic projects many times but still same problem. Please guide me to resolve this.